SwiftUI TipKit wrong order of showing rule based tips
I have a simple view that I want some tips to show. For some reason the wrong tip seems to be showing and I have no clue why. In my reasoning the tip named TestTip.first should be showing but instead TestTip.third is showing.
MRE:
import SwiftUI
import TipKit

enum TestTip: Tip {
    case first, second, third
    
    @Parameter
    static var showFirst: Bool = false
    @Parameter
    static var showSecond: Bool = false
    @Parameter
    static var showThird: Bool = false
    
    var title: Text {
        switch self {
        case .first: Text("First")
        case .second: Text("Second")
        case .third: Text("Third")
        }
    }
    
    var rules: [Rule] {
        switch self {
        case .first: #Rule(Self.$showFirst) { $0 == true }
        case .second: #Rule(Self.$showSecond) { $0 == true }
        case .third: #Rule(Self.$showThird) { $0 == true }
        }
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("First tip")
                .popoverTip(TestTip.first)
            Text("Second tip")
                .popoverTip(TestTip.second)
            Text("Third tip")
                .popoverTip(TestTip.third)
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            TestTip.showFirst = true
        })
    }
}

#Preview {
    TestView()
}


Swift will synthesize an id property for a Tip implementation if you do not explicitly provide one yourself. I'm wondering if this is the problem -- each member of your enum will have the same id.

For these kind to things you might want to check out: TipGroup(.ordered).
